# Create Action in a rails api with json

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, api

I'm trying to build a simple action in a rails controller that will act as an API.

In this case I'm trying to run a create when a client posts a json encoded string.

Right now I have it working looking like this:

```
def create
  @user = User.new.from_json(params[:user])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.json  { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I don't like how i'm dependent on the to_json call through to do the create. Right now I'm only responding to a json payload, but if we decide to extend it to xml this code breaks.

Is there a cleaner way to create a new user from data posted in json format?

I tried just passing in the params[:user] (which is the json string) to User.new but got errors.

For reference my json looks like this:

```
{"email":"email.address@gmail.com","password":"password"}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure but maybe you want to do the `.from_json(params[:user])` part in the `format.json` block?

```
def create
    @user = User.new
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json do
            if @user.from_json(params[:user]).save
               #render user
            else
               #render errors
            end
        end
        format.xml do
            if @user.from_xml(params[:user]).save
            else
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This way it would not break when you'll receive xml.